# How can I set the background of bottom sheet dialog to a specific colour?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

When my bottom sheet opens, I don't want to see the background text. I want to change it to a specific color(#1C1C1E).

This is my bottom sheet when it pops open:

[image: bottom sheet]

Please let me know if more inputs are required from my side.

Thanks in advance!!!!

I tried a few snippet codes, but they were for changing the color of the bottom sheet's background, and not the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
   val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, null)

// Dialog object created
val dialog = Dialog(this)
dialog.setContentView(view)

// change background color
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.custom_background_color))

// Dialog nesnesini göster
dialog.show()
```

Comment: Would it e possible if you can provide custom_background XML?

Comment: I shared the custom background with you now

Comment: I wrote a new code can you try it

Comment: Yes! I cannot find the xml code..

Comment: you need to create a special layout with that name and if you make the design you want on it, your dialog will look like that.

Comment: You can use this code to access any object inside
val btnClose = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnDismiss)